# Get COUNT with a condition from a joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table `SyncHistory`:

```
SyncHistoryId     SyncType     SyncDateTime
-----------------------------------------------------
    55              1       2017-11-28 09:30:51.810
    56              1       2017-11-28 10:30:32.123
```

And then another table `SyncDetails`:

```
SyndDetailId      SyncHistoryId     ItemId     ItemCreated     ItemChanged
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    98                 55           12345          1                 0
    99                 55           23183          1                 0
    100                55           87687          0                 1
    101                55           23234          0                 0
    102                55           23222          0                 0
    103                56           9928           1                 0
```

What I'm trying to do is create a query that gives me this:

```
Sync Data              New          Existing & Changed   Existing & Not Changed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11/28/2017 9:30am       2                 1                    2    
11/28/2017 10:30am      1                 0                    0
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
SELECT 
    sh.SyncHistoryId
    , sh.SyncDateTime
    , count(sd1.SyncDetailId) AS Created
    , count(sd2.SyncDetailId) AS ExistingChanged
    , count(sd3.SyncDetailId) AS ExistingNotChanged
FROM
    SyncHistory sh
    LEFT JOIN SyncDetails sd1 ON sh.SyncHistoryId = sd1.SyncHistoryId AND sd1.ItemCreated = 1 AND sd1.ItemChanged = 0
    LEFT JOIN SyncDetails sd2 ON sh.SyncHistoryId = sd2.SyncHistoryId AND sd2.ItemCreated = 0 AND sd2.ItemChanged = 1
    LEFT JOIN SyncDetails sd3 ON sh.SyncHistoryId = sd3.SyncHistoryId AND sd3.ItemCreated = 0 AND sd3.ItemChanged = 0
WHERE
    sh.SyncType = 1
GROUP BY
    sh.SyncHistoryId
    , sh.SyncDateTime
ORDER BY
    sh.SyncDateTime DESC
```

But, none of the resulting counts are accurate.  I'm doing something wrong, but not sure what.

Comment: Please prepare demo, also grouping by `SyncDateTime` doesn't make sense, probably you want to group by full hour/

Comment: If I don't have that GroupBy, the query throws an error

Comment: Also, how can I prepare a demo?  Is there an online sql demo tool?

Comment: Of course you could use http://rextester.com or http://dbfiddle.uk  Just paste create table + insert into and share link here.

Comment: also sqlfiddle.com

Comment: See my second answer with `NULLIF`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT h.SyncDateTime, 
       SUM(case when d.ItemCreated = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as New,
       SUM(case when d.ItemChanged = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [Existing & Changed],
       SUM(case when d.ItemCreated  = 0 and d.ItemChanged  = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as [Existing & Not Changed]
FROM   SyncHistory h
       INNER JOIN SyncDetails d ON h.SyncHistoryId = d.SyncHistoryId     
GROUP BY h.SyncDateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to `JOIN` to the details table once. You can get your counts from that through aggregation:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), SH.SyncDateTime, 120) AS SyncTime,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SD.ItemCreated = 1 AND SD.ItemChanged = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS New,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SD.ItemCreated = 0 AND SD.ItemChanged = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ExistingAndChanged,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SD.ItemCreated = 0 AND SD.ItemChanged = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ExistingAndNotChanged
FROM
    SyncHistory SH
LEFT OUTER JOIN SyncDetails SD ON SD.SyncHistoryID = SH.SyncHistoryID
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), SH.SyncDateTime, 120)
```

You weren't clear on how the grouping/datetime should be determined. What I have is by the minute. If it's supposed to be by the hour on the 1/2 hour mark or something else then you'll need to change that part of the query in the `GROUP BY` and the first column of the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution. I hope it will work - no `CASE`, no subquery:

```
SELECT 
    sh.SyncHistoryId
    ,sh.SyncDateTime
    ,COUNT( NULLIF( sd.ItemCreated, 0 ) ) AS Created
    ,COUNT( NULLIF( sd.ItemCreated, 1 ) + NULLIF( sd1.ItemChanged, 0 ) ) AS ExistingChanged
    ,COUNT( NULLIF( sd.ItemCreated, 1 ) + NULLIF( sd1.ItemChanged, 1 ) ) AS ExistingNotChanged
FROM
    SyncHistory sh JOIN SyncDetails sd ON sh.SyncHistoryId = sd.SyncHistoryId
WHERE
    sh.SyncType = 1
GROUP BY
    sh.SyncHistoryId
    ,sh.SyncDateTime

ORDER BY
    sh.SyncDateTime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope subquery is not forbidden:

```
SELECT 
    sh.SyncHistoryId
    ,sh.SyncDateTime
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SyncDetails sd WHERE sh.SyncHistoryId = sd.SyncHistoryId AND sd.ItemCreated = 1 AND sd1.ItemChanged = 0) AS Created
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SyncDetails sd WHERE sh.SyncHistoryId = sd.SyncHistoryId AND sd.ItemCreated = 0 AND sd1.ItemChanged = 1) AS ExistingChanged
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SyncDetails sd WHERE sh.SyncHistoryId = sd.SyncHistoryId AND sd.ItemCreated = 0 AND sd1.ItemChanged = 0) AS ExistingNotChanged
FROM
    SyncHistory sh
WHERE
    sh.SyncType = 1
ORDER BY
    sh.SyncDateTime DESC
```

Comment: ok, I was thinking this solution might be slow.  I try to avoid sub queries in the SELECT

Comment: You still think `GROUP BY` is needed here?

Comment: @NiranjanRajawat OK, without GROUP BY. I copied the end of query after WHERE.